# Unknown Sources Error while running Android Location Broadcast Code

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-android-api-2, pubnub

I am trying to compile the Android Location Broadcast code which i downloaded from pubnub site,but I am getting this error while starting sharing my location

> 10-03 21:09:44.219 31344-31344/io.atlanticlab.pubnubmaptracker E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                    Process: io.atlanticlab.pubnubmaptracker, PID: 31344
>                                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                        at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:442)
>                                                                                        at com.pubnub.api.PubnubCore.publish(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                        at com.pubnub.api.Pubnub.publish(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                        at io.atlanticlab.pubnubmaptracker.PubNubManager.broadcastLocation(PubNubManager.java:47)
>                                                                                        at io.atlanticlab.pubnubmaptracker.GMapsShareLocationActivity.onLocationChanged(GMapsShareLocationActivity.java:128)
>                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.nj$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6236)
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:891)
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:781)

Here is my PubNubManager.class

```
public class PubNubManager {

public final static String TAG = "PUBNUB";

public static Pubnub startPubnub() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Initializing PubNub");
    return new Pubnub("demo", "demo");
}

public static void subscribe(Pubnub mPubnub, String channelName, Callback subscribeCallback) {
    // Subscribe to channel
    try {
        mPubnub.subscribe(channelName, subscribeCallback);
        Log.d(TAG, "Subscribed to Channel");
    } catch (PubnubException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
    }
}

public static void broadcastLocation(Pubnub pubnub, String channelName, double latitude,
                                     double longitude, double altitude) {
    JSONObject message = new JSONObject();
    try {
        message.put("lat", latitude);
        message.put("lng", longitude);
        message.put("alt", altitude);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Sending JSON Message: " + message.toString());
    pubnub.publish(channelName, message, publishCallback);
}

public static Callback publishCallback = new Callback() {

    @Override
    public void successCallback(String channel, Object response) {
        Log.d("PUBNUB", "Sent Message: " + response.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void errorCallback(String channel, PubnubError error) {
        Log.d("PUBNUB", error.toString());
    }
};
```

}

Here is the link to whole code 
[link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B11qn6UQwFASNHREWk1XWXA2bTQ)

Comment: which version of the library is this? I do not see com.pubnub.api.PubnubCore in the source code. perhaps move to a newer version...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Can you [enable PubNub client logging](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/android-java/pubnub-android-sdk-troubleshooting-guide), reproduce and share logs? Oh it looks like you are using v3 of the PubNub SDK. If this is a new project, please move to v4 of the SDK.

Comment: Just wondering if you found any resolution here.